# How can I update an attribute of the same entity in a different view controller in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I'm super new at using Core Data and couldn't figure out how to solve this. I have two view controllers: View Controller A and View Controller B.
At the top I have initialized:

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
```

I created a `let newUser = User(context: self.context)` in A, and proceeded to fill it with: `newUser.name = self.label.text`. Now I want to access the same User Object in View Controller B to fill in the age when the user inputs that in. How do I access the same Entity object from Core Data in View Controller B?

Right now I copy and paste the code from View Controller A (like instantiating a new User and the putting in the same context) into View Controller B, and as shown below in View Controller C (where I am outputting both), I am successfully retrieving the name, but not the age:

```
class ViewControllerC: UIViewController {
var users: [User]?

let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

func fetchDriverInfo(){
    //fetch driver's information
    do {
         self.users = try context.fetch(User.fetchRequest())
         self.userName.text = self.users?[0].name        //works
         self.userAge.text =  self.users?[0].age        //doesn't work

   }catch{
        print("Something went wrong")
    }
```

Comment: You have to save the context after modifying the record. And how do you know that the affected user is the **first** one? Core Data fetches the records unordered unless you specify a sort descriptor.

Comment: Yes, I've saved it. I guess my question is- every time I call "new User" does it create a new User entity and store that into the users array? I don't know why I assumed that the context would point to the same user.. how do I get the same user?

Comment: If you want to get a specific user you have to apply a predicate to the fetch request.

Answer (score 0):

Possible problems:

1. there are multiple `User` entities and you are saving one and then reading from a different one.
2. you are not writing or saving the property correctly. It is possible you have a type mismatch on the `age` property and it errors when writing. As it seems like you are reading and writing to the viewContext and have no other contexts you shouldn't *need* to save the context to view the changes to it (but it is a good practice), but if you wrote with another context it must be saved.
3. you are fetching at the wrong time. The object may be updated after you did the fetch and there is some subtle timing issue. I generally suggest to use a FetchedResultsController even to just access and single ManagedObject. I don't like to do direct fetches on core data. It can be hard to handle pointers to ManagedObjects. You are not allowed to access them after they are deleted, and they may update when you aren't expecting them to.

Without seeing your code that writes to core-data it is hard to know exactly what the issue.